# "Seeing is believing: [...]" blog post is untagged

Tags: bug, tags, blog, the-overflow

The Stack Overflow Podcast is now available as video, but the relevant [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/01/seeing-is-believing-the-stack-overflow-podcast-now-available-as-video/) is not tagged:

[image]

Presumably, it should have the "[the stack overflow podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/the-stack-overflow-podcast/)" tag and any other relevant tags.

Comment: What?! Podcast is doing youtube vids and I missed the announcement!? Why did no one tell me?

Comment: Duplicate, we can't possibly report each and every blog post now. There is a bug that cause tags to either disappear or not be created, in all, or at least many, blog posts. Fixing it would fix all posts.

Comment: @bad_coder well due to the bug, there are no tags, hence it's not featured on the sidebar as it used to be. (I think?)

Comment: @Sha: That is no reason to close as a duplicate of a *different* blog post that was untagged. You can post a more general bug report if this happens again, and link that question as a duplicate of this question (if this question doesn't get answered).

Comment: I think this post shouldn't have been closed, it's about 1 specific recent instance that should be fixed asap.

Comment: I didn't notice the older bug report was already in [tag:status-completed], that alone is reason to not choose as duplicate target. Better mention this next time. Anyway, there appears to be bigger bug at action, as many blog posts appear untagged. It makes very little sense that people have to report first, and only then it's "fixed". If this keeps happening better start a generic bug report "Blog posts are created without any tags" and ask SE to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: And this one still not fixed, weird. One time they fix it same day, other times they might take days/weeks/months.